# Can´t render an specific item, flask/sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hey there im trying to program a platform for selling tickets, so when i click on the event as a user i´ll be redirected to a page where the information of the event including the prices and stuff will be shown. For that matter, im trying to print the given price of the ticket for that specific event with no success, i´ve tried many things but those are the ultimate lines i coded. I know how to manipulate lists in python very well but as this is flask/sqalchemy im a little bit confused as the tickets have to be the ones that the event organizer is going to set.

post.html

```
<div class="table-tickets col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin-top-20-xs margin-top-0-md">
    <form method="POST" action="">
      <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr class="title">
              <th class="tg-031e" colspan="2"> 
                <div class="row"> 
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col lg-6"> 
                     <h4 class="kill-top-margin kill-bottom-margin"> Tickets</h4>
                  </div> 
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col lg-6">  
                    {% for info in post.ticket %}
                    <h4 class="kill-top-margin kill-bottom-margin"> ${{ info }} </h4>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <h4 class="kill-top-margin kill-bottom-margin"> ${{ #priceoftheticket }} </h4>
                 </div> 
                </div>
              </th> 
           </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

models

```
class Post(db.Model):
    #unique id for the user
    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    #name of the event
    title= db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    #when the event was posted 
    date_posted= db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now())
    #description of the event
    content= db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    #start date and hour of the event 
    start_dh= db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, default=datetime.now())
    #finish date and hour of the event 
    finish_dh= db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, default=datetime.now())
    #linking the  post table with the user
    user_id= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    #relation with the ticket model
    ticket=db.relationship("Tickets", backref="event", lazy=True)
    #this is a method that declares how our class is going to be printed out 
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s,%s,%s,%s" % (self.user_id,self.title,self.date_posted,self.content)


#data base for the tickets
class Tickets(db.Model):
    #unique id for the user
    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    #name or kind of the event, this is set by the creators
    ticket_type=db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    #initial stock of the ticket
    ticket_quantity=db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    #initial price of this kind of ticket
    price_ticket=db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    #start date and hour of the event 
    start_dh_tickets= db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    #finish date and hour of the event 
    finish_dh_tickets= db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    #id of the event we have a relationship with
    post_id= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post.id"), nullable=False)
    #this is a method that declares how our class is going to be printed out 
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s,%s,%s,%s" % (self.post_id,self.ticket_type, self.ticket_quantity,self.price_ticket)
```

routes

```
@app.route("/post/new",methods=["GET","POST"])  
@login_required
def new_post(): 
    #event forms
    post_form=PostForm()
    #valdiating the submission of those forms
    if post_form.validate_on_submit():
        #generating the submission of the data to our data base
        #post data genetarator
        post=Post(title=post_form.title.data,content=post_form.content.data,start_dh=post_form.start_dh.data,
                   finish_dh=post_form.finish_dh.data,author=current_user)         
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()   
        flash("create your tickets now", "success")        
        return redirect(url_for("tickets"))
    return render_template("create_post.html",title="new post",post_form=post_form,legend="New Event")



#create new tickets
@app.route("/ticket",methods=["GET","POST"])  
@login_required
def tickets():
    ticket_form=TicketForm() 
    #this variable give use the id of the last post that this user posted
    post_relation=Post.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).first()
    #submission
    if  ticket_form.validate_on_submit(): 
        tickets=Tickets(ticket_type=ticket_form.ticket_type.data,ticket_quantity=ticket_form.ticket_quantity.data,
                         price_ticket=ticket_form.price_ticket.data, start_dh_tickets=ticket_form.start_dh_tickets.data,
                         finish_dh_tickets=ticket_form.finish_dh_tickets.data,event=post_relation)  
        db.session.add(tickets)
        db.session.commit() 
        flash("your tickets has been created","success")
        return redirect(url_for("home"))                   
    return render_template("create_ticket.html",title="tickets",ticket_form=ticket_form)   

@app.route("/event")
def event():
    post_form=PostForm()
    ticket_form=TicketForm()
    return render_template("event.html", title="event", post_form=post_form,ticket_form=ticket_form)
```

it´s rendering this way $1, a ,34,12 -> i need only the 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you've got two alternatives here:

1. Just access the property:

   ```
            {% for info in post.ticket %}
            <h4 class="kill-top-margin kill-bottom-margin"> ${{ info }} </h4>
            <h4 class="kill-top-margin kill-bottom-margin"> ${{ info.price_ticket }} </h4>
            {% endfor %}
   ```
2. Or, basing on how it's currently rendered and assuming it's the only place you need `ticket` to be displayed, you could re-implement `__repr__` in `Tickets` class:

   ```
   def __repr__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.price_ticket)
   ```

   But that might have application-wide impact and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: the problem he has is not really with flask, but with sqlalchemy ... when accessing the property for a db model ... sqlalchemy tries to "refresh" it and fails in flask

you have two options:
1. convert your db model into a dict
2. just send the value separately...